# How to re-use blocks of helm code across manifests?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a block of code I'm trying to re-use across several yaml manifest files.

How can I build a function from this that I can re-use across files? I have tried adding a template inside `_helpers.tpl` like below, but no luck!

Does anyone have any tips on how to template this code for re-use?

The template:

```
{{- define "xx" -}}
  {{ range $model := .Values.appConfig.models }}
  {{ range $modelMode := $.Values.appConfig.models }}
{{- end -}}
```

The code to wrap:

```
{{ range $model := .Values.appConfig.models }}
  {{ range $modelMode := $.Values.appConfig.models }}     
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: {{ $modelMode }}
  labels:

  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

My attempt:

```
{{- template "xx" }}
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: {{ $modelMode }}
  labels:

  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of rules around template definitions.

First off: within a `define`...`end` block, all of the inner blocks need to match up; there need to be as many `range` directives as matching `end`s.  In your case, I'd put the `range`...`end` block in the top-level `templates/*.yaml` file and invoke the template inside that.

```yaml
{{- range $model := .Values.appConfig.models -}}
{{- range $modelMode := $.Values.appConfig.models -}}
{{- template "xx" . -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "xx" -}}
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
...
{{ end -}}
```

The Go `text/template` language doesn't have global variables, and a template can't access variables in its caller.  Anything you use in a `define`d template needs to be passed in the template parameter.  Templates only take a single parameter; in Helm, you can pack multiple parameters into a `dict` or a `list`.

The other important detail here is that, normally in Helm, `.` refers to a specific object with `Values`, `Release`, and other properties, but in the Go template language `.` has a couple of other uses as well.  In a defined template, `.` is the parameter.  If you need access to the Helm `.`, maybe to invoke a subtemplate that defines labels, you need to explicitly pass it as a parameter.

This all combines into:

```yaml
{{- range $model := .Values.appConfig.models -}}
{{- range $modelMode := $.Values.appConfig.models -}}
{{- template "xx" (dict "top" $ "modelMode" $modelMode) -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "xx" -}}
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: {{ .modelMode }}
  labels:
{{ include "mychart.labels" .top | indent 4 }}
spec:
  minAvailable: {{ .top.Values.minAvailable }}
{{ end -}}
```

Take note of a couple of things in the last example.  Where we invoke the `template`, we now pass a `dict` as the single parameter.  We can then get the parameters out inside the invoked template with `.modelMode` and `.top`.  If we need the top-level values, those are inside the `.top` object; if we need to invoke another template that needs the top-level object, we need to pass that object, and not the template-specific `.`.

I've also called the label template with `include` rather than `template`.  `include` is a Helm extension that returns the template result as a string, so in this case it can be re-indented.  The two invocation paths are very similar and I might default to using `include` in most cases.